# Google URL Shortener

Tags: url-shortener, google-url-shortener, google-apis-explorer

We are using Google URLShortener for a prototype in an ERP product & currently we can't hit secured apis(https) from our servers. Is there a way, we can get un-secured google api(http).

If not, do we have any other apis which does the same thing & allow us to hit using http?

Comment: If you wish you can setup your own URL shortener https://yourls.org/

Comment: visit tinyurl.com